# Rush Hour 2 dialog

Tags: movies

- [Rush Hour 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI7lnngM1UM)

What was Hu Li (Ziyi Zhang) saying from 00:23 to 00:31 in the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 原來是鼎鼎有名的李督察。告訴你：幹掉你，江湖上我就更有名。

> Look who's here, the famous Chief Inspector Lee. Let me tell you something: once I kill you, I'll become even more famous in the community (of outlaws).